# Revert Android Update 4.0 to 3.0/3.2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, downgrade

Is it possible to downgrade from Android version 4.0(ICS) to 3.0(Honeycomb) after upgrading to ICS? Can any one help me.

Comment: Can you please clarify and give some more details: What device are you using? Is it currently running Android 3.2, and you want to downgrade to 3.0 -- or the other way around? Apart from that: A "version switch" can be done by flashing the corresponding ROM, so you might want to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: if i upgrade 3.0 to 4.0 , i don't like 4.0 i want 3.0 again can i go back to 3.0 in Samsung s2.

Comment: Honeycomb is specific to tablets not phones. The only way is to flash a custom rom based on 3.0 but I doubt you will find any.Check the xda developers site for your device.

Comment: ok i want after upgrade can we upgrade previous one

Answer (score 2):

As I already wrote in my comment: A downgrade (as well as an upgrade) can be performed by flashing the corresponding ROM (for references, see [other downgrade questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downgrade?sort=votes)). To find a matching ROM, please see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). For the process of flashing, you might want to check with the [rom-flashing](/questions/tagged/rom-flashing) tag, especially the [questions dealing with the SGS2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rom-flashing+samsung-galaxy-s-2).

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade to previous versions by flashing the Correspondings ROMS. The Downgrade is possible, only if the downgraded version is compatible with your device. HoneyComb is designed for Tablets. its not supported for smartphones. If Samsung GS2 is your devices, then HoneyComb is not supported, rather you can downgrade to pervious GB versions.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't believe that 3.0 Honeycomb is compatible with phones. Although, there might be a Honeycomb ROM on the Internet.